# How to query the custom fields by language?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, custom-field, multi-language

For each post, there is a custom field name "Function", the key/value pair is like this:

```
Key : Functions
Value : <!--en-->Nourishing Yin and invigorating the vital essence of kidneys.<!--:--><!--tw-->滋陰補腎。<!--:-->
```

The problem is if I simply use get_post_meta , it return string of both language, how can I get the value based on the language?

I am using qTranslate right now, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In qTranslate, there is this function that "dispatch" the language with the kind of string you have.

Haven't tested it yet, but you could do something like:

```
$myString = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'Functions', true);
echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage($myMeta);
```

This will display the right language on your post based on the current page's language.